# .htaccess url rewriting is not working for me

Tags: php, .htaccess

i want to change this url

```
http://localhost/ramadel/view/product.php?product=71
```

to

```
http://localhost/ramadel/view/product/71
```

here is my htaccess code:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?product/([0-9]+)$ /product.php?product=$1`

and rewrite model in httdp.conf is uncommented too.

any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the best at .htaccess in general, kinda learning myself. Give this a try, got flags to make case insensitive

```
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)/?$ product.php?product=$1 [NC,L]
```